# Pandas, combining information from 2 dataframes and one dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, string-comparison

Well this is a bit difficult to explain....

Suppose you have 2 pandas dataframes and 1 dictionary.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['b', 'c','d'])
df1['a'] = pd.Series(['1 A1-1','3 A1-1','8 A1-2','17 A1-3','45 A1-16'], index=df1.index)
df1 = df1.reindex_axis(sorted(df1.columns), axis=1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame([['1 A1-1',5],['2 A1-1',8],['3 A1-1',10],['8 A1-2',4],['17 A1-3',1],['45 A1-16',2]], columns = ['m','n'])

dt = {'A1-1':100, 'A1-2':150, 'A1-3':200, 'A1-4':250, 'A1-5':300, 'A1-16':950}
```

`df1['a']` and `df2['m']` contain `IDs`, some are identical. `df2['n']` contains additional values. `dt` contains basic values for `ID` groups like `A1-1`, `A1-2` etc.

I would now like to compare/combine the data in `df1`, `df2` and `dt` so that I'm able to add a new column to `df1`:
Whenever the `IDs` in `df1['a']` and `df2['m']` are identical the basic value from the dictionary with the same string part is added to the corresponding `df2['n']` and the result is then transfered into a new column in `df1['e']`.

One major problem I have is the string handling in the IDs and the dict keys: e.g  `'1 A1-1'` in `df1` and `df2` and `'A1-1'` in `dt` - don't know how to compare them.

Most helpful would be a result like `df1['e'] = pd.Series([105,110,154,201,952], index = df1.index)`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is very nice explained question.

First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace column `a` and select second lists with `str[1]` and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` and add  `map`ed column `a` by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1['e'] = df1['a'].str.split().str[1].map(dt) + df1['a'].map(df2.set_index('m')['n'])
print (df1)
          a         b         c         d    e
0    1 A1-1  0.026375  0.260322 -0.395146  105
1    3 A1-1 -0.204301 -1.271633 -2.596879  110
2    8 A1-2  0.289681 -0.873305  0.394073  154
3   17 A1-3  0.935106 -0.015685  0.259596  201
4  45 A1-16 -1.473314  0.801927 -1.750752  952
```

EDIT:

map function use keys of dict for replace by values in some column. Similary map by Series, only instaed keys are used `index` values and instead `values` use values.

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['bar','foo', 'baz'], 'b':[7,8,9]})
print (df)
     a  b
0  bar  7
1  foo  8
2  baz  9

#dict and df for mapping
d = {'foo':15, 'bar':20}
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'m':['baz','bar','foo'], 'n':[3,4,5]})
print (df2)
     m  n
0  baz  3
1  bar  4
2  foo  5

#create Series for map
print (df2.set_index('m')['n'])
m
baz    3
bar    4
foo    5
Name: n, dtype: int64

df['c'] = df['a'].map(d)
df['d'] = df['a'].map(df2.set_index('m')['n'])
print (df)
     a  b     c  d
0  bar  7  20.0  4
1  foo  8  15.0  5
2  baz  9   NaN  3
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot. Although, I do not grasp entirely the function of map in that case. Would you please be so kind as to give me a brief explanation.